# jsoniter how to prevent print null to json

Tags: java, json

I use **Jsoniter** to deserialize jsons and serialize objects to json. I have an object with many properties and add them as json member by `@JsonProperty("xxx")`. when use the following code for print json message of an object:

```
JsonStream.serialize(this);
```

I see members with null value in output.
required:

```
{"title":"Clean Code","price":42}
```

but I see:

```
{"title":"Clean Code","author":null,"price":42}
```

How to prevent printing null members (*author* in this example) in **Jsoniter**? (something like `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` in **Jackson**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this requirement is an [open issue](https://github.com/json-iterator/java/issues/245)

**Workaround:** According to the provided link you should use `JsonProperty` like
`@JsonProperty(defaultValueToOmit = "null")` to ignore the null fields.

Comment: Thank you! When I use this property over `get` method it works.